# How to refer/access for each value from one resource block to another resource block terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

> I want to refer the one resource block value to another resource block.
> From the first resource block I have used **for each** to get the application ID and from the second resource block  do not have any for each block but I need application ID here to create app registration.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "<=2.39.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {

}

data "azuread_application" "example" {
  for_each = toset(var.application_ids)
  application_id = each.value
}

resource "azuread_application" "current" {
  display_name = "terraform-sp-${var.display_name}"
  owners       = tolist([data.azuread_application.example[each.value].object_id, data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id])

}
```

**error**

Reference to "each" in context without for_each
│
│   on main.tf line 23, in resource "azuread_application" "current":
│   23:   owners       = tolist([data.azuread_application.example[each.key].object_id, data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id])
The "each" object can be used only in "module" or "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set.

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I have pasted error above.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use splat expression `*` and `concat`:

```
owners       = concat(values(data.azuread_application.example)[*].object_id, [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id])
```

Comment: While I'm using above expression having below error :│ This object does not have an attribute named "object_id"